# Combining filters in boost log

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log

I use **boost log** and want to define a **composed filter**. I use `boost::log::init_from_stream`to read the configuration from a stream. Filtering on single conditions works fine. I can do

```
Filter = "%Channel% = A"
```

to get only log entries from channel A. I can do

```
Filter = "%Severity% >= warn"
```

to get only log entries that have a severity which is warning or above.

**Here comes the question:** I want to do someting like

```
Filter = "   (%Channel% = A AND %Severity% >= warn)
          OR (%Channel% = B AND %Severity% >= info)"
```

I was not able to find any documentation regarding such a combination of filters. Is there a way to do this when using `boost::log::init_from_stream`?

Comment: a link to the docs you use would not be remiss

Comment: It wasn't a long search. See my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found this documentation page which documents the grammar:

- [Filter and formatter parsers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/log/doc/html/log/detailed/utilities.html#log.detailed.utilities.setup.filter_formatter)

  ```
  filter:
      condition { op condition }

  op:
      &
      and
      |
      or

  condition:
      !condition
      not condition
      (filter)
      %attribute_name%
      %attribute_name% relation operand

  relation:
      >
      <
      =
      !=
      >=
      <=
      begins_with
      ends_with
      contains
      matches
  ```

Using this, the example given in the question can be expressed as follows:

```
Filter = "(%Channel% = A & %Severity% >= warn) | (%Channel% = B & %Severity% >= info)"
```

Comment: Thank you, how could I have missed it :)

Comment: If I were to make an educated guess: you were looking for sample filter strings. They're absent :)

Comment: Yes, this was what I mostly was looking for :)